# How to align column values with their matching value in another column?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros, alignment

I have several columns of data that I need to align with a master column.

The following is an example of what I hope to achieve, but with a table containing more larger strings and more rows. The data in each row is unique, only appearing once. So I just aim to align those unique values in columns B, C and D with that of A which contains the complete list of possible strings. Also the values in each column are sorted, so it is case of bumping cells down until they align with Column A, which is what I have been doing manually for now but want to automate:

[image: Example screenshot]

I have limited experience with Excel, but all research has led me to this code to use in a module. Unfortunately when it is run, it doesn't do much for me. On second attempt, to the best of my abilities I tried adjusting the code to suit the range of values in my sheet but I can't get it to run. So I'm hoping if more experienced members inform me if I actually need to make the code suit my data or it should just work? Thanks for any help you can give or simply taking the time to read!

```
Option Explicit
Sub AlignCustNbr()
' hiker95, 01/10/2011
' http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=520077
'
' The macro was modified from code by:
' Krishnakumar, 12/12/2010
' http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=148881
'
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long, a As Long
Dim CustNbr As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
LR = ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("E3:G" & LR).Sort Key1:=ws.Range("E3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
   OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
LR = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("A3:C" & LR).Sort Key1:=ws.Range("A3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo, _
   OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    Set CustNbr = ws.Range("A2:C" & LR)
    a = 2
    Do While CustNbr.Cells(a, 1) <> ""
    If CustNbr.Cells(a, 1).Offset(, 4) <> "" Then
    If CustNbr.Cells(a, 1) < CustNbr.Cells(a, 1).Offset(, 4) Then
      CustNbr.Cells(a, 1).Offset(, 4).Resize(, 3).Insert -4121
    ElseIf CustNbr.Cells(a, 1) > CustNbr.Cells(a, 1).Offset(, 4) Then
      CustNbr.Cells(a, 1).Resize(, 3).Insert -4121
      LR = LR + 1
      Set CustNbr = ws.Range("A3:C" & LR)
    End If
   End If
  a = a + 1
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
End Sub!
```

Comment: Is [the screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HNwkh.png) an example of the input and its expected output, or the result of your code? If it's not an example of the expected results, please add that (including edge cases, such as: are the values in the input unique, and sorted?), to explain what your *"several columns of data that I need to align with a master column"* means.

Comment: @Arjan Hi, apologies. I'll clarify further. The example is simply an example. It is not a result of the code. Simply what I hope to achieve, but with a table containing more larger strings and more rows. Further information is that the data in each row is unique, only appearing once. So I just aim to align those unique values in columns B, C and D with that of A which contains the complete list of possible strings. Also the values in each column are sorted, so it is case of bumping cells down until they align with Column A, which is what I have been doing manually for now but want to automate.

Comment: No need for any macro, unless you really don't want additional columns. I'd look into [the `VLOOKUP` formula](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65) and use extra columns (or a separate worksheet) for the result.

Comment: As for *"Also the values in each column are sorted"*: that is not true in your example...? (But not a problem for `VLOOKUP`, when its 4th parameter is `FALSE`.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so good in VBA but this code can do that:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AlignCustNbr()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For i = 2 To ws.Columns.Count
        If (Trim(ws.Cells(1, i).Value & "") = "") Then
            Exit For
        End If
        '
        Call Align2Columns(ws, 1, i)
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub Align2Columns(ws As Worksheet, mainCol As Long, dataCol As Long)
    Dim colData() As String
    Dim strTemp As String, strTemp2 As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim lastDataRow As Integer

    ReDim colData(1 To ws.Rows.Count)
    lastDataRow = 1
    '
    'Findeing aligned datas to colData()
    For i = 1 To ws.Rows.Count
        strTemp = Trim(ws.Cells(i, dataCol).Value & "")
        If (strTemp = "") Then
            Exit For
        End If
        '
        For j = 1 To ws.Rows.Count
            strTemp2 = Trim(ws.Cells(j, mainCol).Value & "")
            If (strTemp2 = "") Then
                lastDataRow = lastDataRow + 1
                colData(j + lastDataRow) = strTemp2
                Exit For

            ' to avoid cese sensetive use commented line
            'ElseIf (UCase(strTemp) = UCase(strTemp2)) Then
            ElseIf (strTemp = strTemp2) Then
                colData(j) = strTemp2
                Exit For

            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    '
    'Update dataCol
    i = 0
    Do
        i = i + 1
        ws.Cells(i, dataCol).Value = colData(i)
        If (Trim(ws.Cells(i, mainCol).Value & "") = "") Then
            lastDataRow = lastDataRow - 1
        End If
    Loop While lastDataRow > 0
End Sub
```